# Adding Glassfish server adapter on Eclipse in Android Developer Tools (ADT)

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, adt

I have the ADT bundle on linux ubuntu 13.04 and am trying to add the Glassfish server adapter.  When I try To do File >> New >> Other >> Server and select the Glassfish tools shown below:
[image: Selecting Glassfish Tools]

After I click the next button this is what I got.
[image: Errors displayed when installing Glassfish tools]

How do I solve the errors and get the Glassfish server tools adapter to install.

Comment: I would guess the version of your Eclipse is not supported by Glashfish Tools which again in turn needs the Eclipse Data Tools

Comment: What do you suggest as the best solution in this case, because i need to deploy on glassfish while also using the ADT for my android development.

Comment: Are you looking to have server side written in Java and then use the sevlets etc using AJAX / or rest services from your application? I dont have experience with GlassFish tools, but you can easily run your Java web apps by adding a Tomact server in Eclipse. You dont really need the fancy Glassfish tools